# Android Studio debug for doInBackground code of an AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-studio

I put some break points in my doInBackground() code of AsyncTask class. But when I am debugging the application, control is not going over doInBackground(). Please help me regarding this.

Comment: If you put a Log instead of braekpoint, do you see it ?

Comment: @ben75 yes, I am able to see by printing logs

Answer (score 8):

Put the following code fragment in the beginning of `doInBackground`:

`android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();`

Then when you set a breakpoint in that thread, eclipse will find it.

In your emulator,

- Go to **Dev Settings**`.
- Click on Select Debug App
- Select the app which you are going to debug
- The checkbox "Wait for Debugger" will be enabled. Check this checkbox

Now try running the app again.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this way also, But still same issue.

Comment: Do you have <manifest android:debuggable="true"> in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Still getting the same issue

Comment: Refer edit regarding dev settings in emulator. Check and let me know if it helps.

Comment: I am working on device not simulator

Comment: You have to do the same for the device also. Go to settings --> Developer option and follow the steps

Comment: I am having the same/similar problems
Using a real device... Android Studio does hit breakpoints but is unable to step through code or even restart at all (hangs)